# Web interface not connected to blockchain variables

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

Contract works fine in Remix, but there are issues with the web UI.

The deployed contract variable is set properly and all functions are visible in the browser console, but the functions are not working.
Web3 is installed, Ganache running ...everything looks ok...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract mycontract {    
  struct student {
    bytes32 sid;
    string name;
    uint64 gender;
  }

  mapping (bytes32 =>student) s1;
  student[] public stu;

  function setstudent(bytes32 sid, string name, uint64 gender) public {        
    s1[sid].sid=sid;
    s1[sid].name=name;
    s1[sid].gender=gender;
  }

  function getstudent(bytes32 sid) public constant returns(bytes32, string, uint64) {
    return(s1[sid].sid,s1[sid].name,s1[sid].gender);
  }
}
```

Client:

```
<script>
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
}
else
{
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
}
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var myContract = web3.eth.contract('MY ABI PASTED HERE');
var student = myContract.at('MY DEPLOYED ADDRESS HERE');
console.log(student);
student.getstudent("1",function(error, result){
if(!error) {
    $("#heading").html("Welcome...");
    $("#studentname").html(web3.toAscii(result[1]));
        console.log(result);
}
else
    console.error(error);
});

$("#save").click(function() {         
  student.setStudent( $("#uid").val(), $("#studentname").val(), 
  $("#gender").val());    
};   
</script>
```

Comment: you might need to post your front-end code, especially the javascript part (web3js)

Comment: Hi, I have added the script too, can u help me??

Comment: "but the functions are not working" can you be more specific?

Comment: getStudent(),setStudent() functions work perfect in Remix,but from Web UI it's not working...

Comment: Are you connecting through MetaMask or using a local RPC node? If you're using a local RPC node, please add your start script (Is the port correct? Usually, the default is port 8545.). It would also help if you include any error messages you're receiving.

Comment: I am using Ganache running at port 7545.No errors, but no interaction with blockchain...Browser console is displaying deployed contract, but there also these functions are not working .